# Implement revision number while keeping primary key in sql

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Suppose I have a psql table with a primary key and some data:

```
         pkey         | price 
----------------------+-------
 0075QlyLvw8bi7q6XJo7 |    20
(1 row)
```

However, I would like to save historical updates on it without losing the functionality that comes from referencing it's key in other tables as foreign keys.

I am thinking of doing some kind of revision_number + timestamp approach where each "update" would be a new row, example:

```
         pkey         | price | rev_no
----------------------+-------+--------
 0075QlyLvw8bi7q6XJo7 |    20 |     0
----------------------+-------+--------
 0075QlyLvw8bi7q6XJo7 |    15 |     1
(2 rows)
```

Then create a view that always takes the highest revision number of the table and reference keys from that view.

However to me this workaraound seems a bit too heavy for a task that in my opinion should be fairly common. Is there something I'm missing? Do you have a better solution or is there a well known paradigm for these types of problems which I don't know about?

Comment: You could move the old values into a history table, so that your main table only contains the most recent version. This could e.g. be done in a trigger

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. You should only consider 1) which operations need to be fast 2) how many revisions do you want to keep 3) how to get rid of old data. The exact solution will depend on these.

Comment: The data revisioning is a core feature in many business applications but it is not implemented as a predefined solution at the data base level. You have to implement it according to your needs and it could be much more complicated than the solution you currently think about.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `PKey` is actually the defined primary key you cannot do the revision scheme you outlined without creating a history table and moving old data to it. The primary key **must be unique** for any revision. But if you have a properly normalized table there several valid method, the following is one:

1. Review the other attributes and identify the candidate business keys (columns of business meaning that could be defined unique -- perhaps the item name.
2. If not already present add 2 columns: effective timestamp and superseded timestamp.
3. Now create a partial unique index on the identified column,from #1) and the superseded timestamp being a column meaning *this is the currently active version*.
4. Create a simple view as `Select * from table`. Since this is a simple view it is fully update-able. Use this View for Select,Insert and Delete, but
5. for Update create an instead of trigger. This trigger will set the superseded timestamp of the current active row and insert a new row update applied and the updated the version number.

With the above you can get you uniquely keep on the current active revision. Further you maintain the history of all relationships at each version. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bdafc4d8a0aaca9242326147b5435652), including a couple useful functions)